# Alea does not dispose memory correctly

Tags: f#, aleagpu

The following F# code crashes on the third call with a no memory exception. Either I am missing something or Alea is not freeing memory correctly for some reason. I've tried it in both F# Interactive and Compiled. I've also tried calling dispose manually, but it did not work. Any idea why?

```
let squareGPU (inputs:float[]) =
        use dInputs = worker.Malloc(inputs)
        use dOutputs = worker.Malloc(inputs.Length)
        let blockSize = 256
        let numSm = worker.Device.Attributes.MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT
        let gridSize = Math.Min(16 * numSm, divup inputs.Length blockSize)
        let lp = new LaunchParam(gridSize, blockSize)
        worker.Launch <@ squareKernel @> lp dOutputs.Ptr dInputs.Ptr inputs.Length
        dOutputs.Gather()


let x = squareGPU [|0.0..0.001..100000.0|]
printfn "1" 
let y = squareGPU [|0.0..0.001..100000.0|]
printfn "2" 
let z = squareGPU [|0.0..0.001..100000.0|]
printfn "3"
```

Comment: Not knowing anything about aleagpu, I find it odd that you would call `dOutputs.Gather()`, but not `dInputs.Gather()`. I assume this is the clean up which follows a call to `Malloc()`.

Comment: No, `Gather()` just copies the data from GPU to host memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you got `System.OutOfMemoryException`, right? That doesn't mean GPU device memory running out, it means you are running out your host memory. in your example, you created a rather large array in host, and you calculate it, and you gather another large array as output. The point is, you use different variable name (x, y and z) to store the output array, and thus GC will have no chance to free it, so eventually you will run out your host memory.

I did a very simple test (I use the stop value 30000 instead 100000 as in your example), this test only uses host code, no GPU code:

```
let x1 = [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
printfn "1" 
let x2 = [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
printfn "2" 
let x3 = [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
printfn "3"
let x4 = [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
printfn "4"
let x5 = [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
printfn "5"
let x6 = [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
printfn "6"
```

And I ran this code in F# interactive (which is a 32bit process), I got this:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 12.0.30815.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> 
1
2
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.EnsureCapacity(Int32 min)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0002>.$FSI_0002.main@() in C:\Users\Xiang\Documents\Inbox\ConsoleApplication6\Script1.fsx:line 32
Stopped due to error
>
```

So that means, after I created 2 such large array (x1 and x2), I ran out of the host memory.

To further confirm this, I use same variable name, which gives GC the chance to collect the old array, and this time it works:

```
let foo() =
    let x = [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "1" 
    let x = [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "2" 
    let x = [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "3"
    let x = [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "4"
    let x = [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "5"
    let x = [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "6"

> 

val foo : unit -> unit

> foo()
;;
1
2
3
4
5
6
val it : unit = ()
>
```

and if I add GPU kernel it still works:

```
let foo() =
    let x = squareGPU [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "1" 
    let x = squareGPU [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "2" 
    let x = squareGPU [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "3"
    let x = squareGPU [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "4"
    let x = squareGPU [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "5"
    let x = squareGPU [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "6"
    let x = squareGPU [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "7"
    let x = squareGPU [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|]
    printfn "8"

> foo();;
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
val it : unit = ()
>
```

Alternatively, you can try to use 64bit process.

Comment: You are right. The way I tested it originally in Interactive mode is by repeatedly calling squareGPU [|0.0..0.001..100000.0|] without any let bindings. For some reason when you do that repeatedly on the same line it does not trigger GC. Even executing [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|] without any function calls causes the memory to clog up. I wonder what is up with this?

Comment: Uhmm, then I don't know what is wrong, you can see, I ran it 8 times and it works fine. Do you mind to post the test that doesn't have the host memory issue?

Comment: Your example works for me and does free up memory properly when the variables go out of scope. If you open the task manager while executing [|0.0..0.001..30000.0|][|0.0..0.001..30000.0|] in F# Interactive, not inside a function, but in the main scope you will see what I mean. The memory usage should go up, without being freed due to it never going out of scope. As you say in the following post, the GC works in a separate thread. Thanks you for the lesson. I wish I had reps so I could actually upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

GC works in a separate background thread, so if you new huge arrays frequentely, it will easily throw that out of memory exception.

In this big array case, I suggest you to use a "in-place modification" style, that will be more stable. I created a test to show that: (NOTE, since the array is very big, you'd better go to project property page, in the Build tab, uncheck the "Prefer 32-bit", to make sure it runs as 64 bit process)

```
open System
open Alea.CUDA
open Alea.CUDA.Utilities
open NUnit.Framework

[<ReflectedDefinition>]
let squareKernel (outputs:deviceptr<float>) (inputs:deviceptr<float>) (n:int) =
    let start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x
    let stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x
    let mutable i = start 
    while i < n do
        outputs.[i] <- inputs.[i] * inputs.[i]
        i <- i + stride

let squareGPUInplaceUpdate (worker:Worker) (lp:LaunchParam) (hData:float[]) (dData:DeviceMemory<float>) =
    // instead of malloc a new device memory, you just reuse the device memory dData
    // and scatter new data to it.
    dData.Scatter(hData)
    worker.Launch <@ squareKernel @> lp dData.Ptr dData.Ptr hData.Length
    // actually, there should be a counterpart of data.Scatter(hData) like data.Gather(hData)
    // but unfortunately, that is missing, but there is a workaround of using worker.Gather.
    worker.Gather(dData.Ptr, hData)

let squareGPUManyTimes (iters:int) =
    let worker = Worker.Default

    // actually during the many iters, you just malloc 2 host array (for data and expected value)
    // and you malloc a device array. You keep reusing them, since they are big array.
    // if you new the huge array very frequentely, GC is under pressure. and since GC works
    // as a separate thread, so you will get System.OutOfMemoryException from time to time.
    let hData = [|0.0..0.001..100000.0|]
    let n = hData.Length
    let expected = Array.zeroCreate n
    use dData = worker.Malloc<float>(n)

    let rng = Random()
    let update () =
        // in-place updating the data
        for i = 0 to n - 1 do
            hData.[i] <- rng.NextDouble()
            expected.[i] <- hData.[i] * hData.[i]

    let lp =
        let blockSize = 256
        let numSm = worker.Device.Attributes.MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT
        let gridSize = Math.Min(16 * numSm, divup n blockSize)
        new LaunchParam(gridSize, blockSize)

    for i = 1 to iters do
        update()
        squareGPUInplaceUpdate worker lp hData dData
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, hData)
        printfn "iter %d passed..." i

[<Test>]
let test() =
    squareGPUManyTimes 5
```

Please note, exception `System.OutOfMemoryException` ALWAYS means host memory, the GPU memory will throw CUDAException if it find there is not enough memory.

BTW, each time you call DeviceMemory.Gather(), it will a new a .NET array and fill it. By using the in-place method shown in this example, you provide a .net array and let it to be filled by the data from the device.